# Enabling Symfony's AppCache replaces Doctrine's ApcCache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, apc

When enabling `AppCache` in my Symfony application, suddenly any injected `ApcCache` gets replaced with `AppCache` instances, yielding:

> Argument passed to MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache, instance of AppCache given

The injection happens through:

```
services:
    my_class:
        class: MyClass
        arguments:
            - @cache
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

Which seems very weird. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is some cache service? Try to rename `cache` service to something else like `apc_cache`.

Comment: Did you try to clear your OpCode cache?

Comment: Renaming the `cache` service to `apc_cache` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the previous response and my analyze, it seems that when using the http cache ($kernel = new AppCache($kernel); in app.php), Symfony create a @cache variable which is an instance of AppCache. It will override the @cache variable you created. Thus name differently your variable like :

```
services:
    my_class:
        class: MyClass
        arguments:
            - @apc_cache
    apc_cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

It seems to be a bug of Symfony3.0.3